# Get resources images from variable

Tags: android, adapter, android-resources, android-image

I have a class called **Monster.class** which contains String type variables.

Another class **MonsterAdapter.class** use the getters to get the values and set on MyGridView.

It works fine but only if I set the image manual like this:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1);
```

**(a1 is the name of the image)**

If I try to use this:

```
final Monster m = monsters[position];
    String variableValue = m.getImg();
    imageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(variableValue, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

It says can't not resolve method "getResources()" and "getPackageName()" and I only can import static method which throws error:

[image]

**ERROR**

[image]

Comment: OOP/programming basics: you cannot call method which doesnt exists ... getResources method belongs to some class if you are not deriving from such class this method doesn't exists(in given scope)

Comment: Just pass the activity context in Adapter constructor &  imageView.setImageResource(mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(variableValue, "drawable", getPackageName()));

Comment: Thanks Zala, really usefull.

Comment: you have to pass through basic Java lessons before starting android, or you gonna face a tone more such questions.

Comment: imageView.setImageResource(getActivity.getApplicationContext.getResources().getIdentifier(variableValue, "drawable", getPackageName()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define Context inner class MonsterAdapter

```
public class MonsterAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
 Context mContext;
 public MonsterAdapter(Context context, ...){
  this.mContext = context;
  ...
 }
}
```

then you can use

```
imageView.setImageResource(mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(variableValue, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting values inside Adapter, then use like below

```
imageView.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(variableValue, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
```

You can create Object for Context inside your adapter and create constructor for it

example:

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context mContext;

  public YourAdapter(Context context){
     this.mContext = context;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i had the context in my adapter :)

Comment: Not for the moment, what i need to specify in the defpackage?

Comment: You have to pass your package name, which you can find in your manifest file. Instead of context.getPackageName(), you can directly specify your package Name like "com.example.etc.."     Try and let me know If you face any issue, If possible paste your adapter class in question

Comment: Can you check it?